# Keyboard remapping SHIFT_L to '(' and holding SHIFT_L to normal SHIFT_L)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

If I just pressed SHIFT_L (i.e. left shift button), I want it to type `(` & if I am using SHIFT_L for a combination to work it like normal SHIFT_L.

Eg:

```
(typed key) ==> (expectation)
SHIFT_L     ==> (
SHIFT_L + e ==> E
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want the left Shift key to type a character all by itself?  The key mapping tools are Ukelele and Karabiner, but I don't know if they can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the behavior of SHIFT_L (and SHIFT_R) download, install and start [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Open the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences... in the menubar, search for *shift* and enable the custom key binding like in the example below (FYI KeyRemap4MacBook shown in the screenshot is the predecessor of Karabiner):

[image]

This enables writing `(` by simply pressing SHIFT_L and `)` by simply pressing SHIFT_R using an us-american keyboard layout with the keys 9|( and 0|). In combination with letters the common function is kept.

If you have a different keyboard layout (e.g. german with 8|( and 9|) you have to create a custom key binding. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*. Then open *Open private.xml* and add:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Change Shift Keys</name>
    <item>
      <name>Shift to Shift</name>
      <appendix>(+ When you type (left or right) Shift only, send the appropriate parenthesis on german keyboard)</appendix>
      <identifier>remap.shiftparensgerman</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
      <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_R, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R</autogen>
    </item>
  </item>
</root>
```

Save the file, switch back to *Change Key*, press ReloadXML ad enable the new key binding. Usually it's the first one listed.